# Extending raster after rasterizing geodataframe using geocube

Tags: python, raster, xarray, geocube

I have created rasterized a geodataframe using geocube `make_geocube`.
The resulting `xr.Dataset` now has the extent of the underlying geodataframe vector data.
Say, the bounding box would be covering Europe.
However, I would love to have the `xr.DataSet` at global extent, i.e. covering all cells from -180 to 180 longitude and -90 to 90 latitude at the spatial resolution used in `make_geocube`.

Is there a way to do that *without* using GDAL functions directly?

Potentially the `geom` argument in `make_geocube`?

Many thanks in advance!